# Header is visible in navigation Experimental on slide transition of page in react-native

Tags: react-native

I have returned null in renderHeader of my application's first page, still the first page header is visible on slide transition from second to first page.  [Same problem I am having](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9656) How do I remove it.

Comment: Can you describe your problem a bit more. Such as what is the navigation flow? Do you start with the first scene go to the second and go back to the first? Right now this question doesn't provide any context or visualization to the bug. Code samples may help too.

Comment: See the link that I have given above...The same problem I am having.

Comment: Then you should follow the suggestion on that issue. If you're unable to provide any contextual info, can't help.